# $\forall g, h, i, n \in \Bbb N, \ g, i > 1, g \neq 10^n, 3h, 3h - 1, (3h)^i \pm 1$. Square $g$, sum its digits, square result, etc...you'll reach $13$

Tags: number-theory

$$\LARGE \text{The $13$ Conjecture}$$

---

Let $i$ be a positive integer and $g$ a positive integer which is not of the forms $3h, \ 3h-1, \ (3h)^m \pm 1$ for some natural $h, \ m$ greater than $1$, and $g \neq 10^n$ for some natural $n$. $δ(n)$ is the sum of digits of $n$ in base $10$. Consider the two sequences created by applying sum of digits and rising to the $2i$-th power **alternatively** to $g$.

> **Conjectures:**
>
> 1. If $i=1$, the two sequences reach the periodic point with $13$.
> 2. If $i > 1$ then the two sequences reach a fixed point of the function $δ(n^{2i})$

An example to illustrate:

Let $g = 13, \ i = 1$, the first sequence is: $$13^2 = 169 \to 1 + 6 + 9 = 16 \to 16^2 = 256 \to 2 + 5 + 6 = \boxed{13}$$

The second sequence is: $$1 + 3 = 4 \to 4^2 = 16 \to 1 + 6 = 7 \to 7^2 = 49 \to 4 + 9 = \boxed{13}$$

Now let $g = 13, \ i = 2$, the first sequence is: $$13^4 = 28561 \to 2 + 8 + 5 + 6 + 1 = 22 \to 22^4 = 234256 \to 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 = 20$$ $$\to 20^4 = 16000 \to 1 + 6 + 0 + 0 + 0 = 7 \to 7^4 = 2401 \to 2 + 4 + 0 + 1 \to 7$$
Indeed, $7$ is a fixed point.

the second sequence is: $$1 + 3 = 4 \to 4^4 = 256 \to 2 + 5 + 6 = 13 \to \ldots \to 7$$

Comment: Don't you get into a loop with $i=1$ and $g=3$ or $g=9$?

Comment: It seems that $f_1(8)\to 1$ is a counterexample.

Comment: That's even easier :)

Comment: @Mathematician42 $g \neq 3h, (3h)^3 - 1, 18h \pm 1$ it is mentioned. According to what *mathlove* said, I believe I can change it so that $g \neq (3h)^n - 1$ so that way $f_1(8) \to 1$ does not apply and so doesn't $f_1(80) \to 1$, but then $f_1(2) \to 13$ would be a counter-example...

Comment: I could say that $g \neq (3h)^2 - 1$ so $g \neq 8, 35, 80, 143, \ldots$ where $δ(g) = 8$ so I am putting that in.

Comment: @user477343: $f_1(10^n)\to 1$ are counterexamples.

Comment: @mathlove Then I guess $g \neq (3h)^m \pm 1$ for which $m \in \mathbb{Z}_{>1}$

Comment: You don't exclude $g=100$ since $100$ is not of the form $(3h)^m\pm 1$.

Comment: @mathlove it is when $m = 1$ and $h = 33$..... OH JEEZ. Ok, changing it again. This time, $h > 1$

Comment: Are you allowing $m=1$ now? because you just disallowed all natural numbers $3h, 3h\pm 1$

Comment: Ok DONE! Edited it, and if there is a counter-example, this conjecture is false

Comment: So $\delta(n)$ is just the sum of the digits of $n$?

Comment: @JackM yes it is

Comment: @user477343 Then the set notation is wrong. Actually, your notation is a complete *mess*, and it seems to be getting worse with every edit. Do you want to work out a simpler way of expressing what you're trying to say in chat?

Comment: @JackM yes please

Comment: @user477343 https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67495/13-conjecture

Comment: @JackM I answered my own post. Look down below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with many (but [not all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture)!) dynamical systems on the integers, this one can be completely analyzed with a bit of computer brute force.

Let $f(x)=\delta(x^2)$. Then for sufficiently large $x$, we have $f(x)\leq x$. Proof: since squaring a number at most doubles the number of digits, then denoting $n(x)$ the number of digits of $x$, we have $f(x)\leq 9\cdot2n(x)$. But we also have $x\geq 10^{n(x)-1}$. We end up with $f(x)\leq x$ as long as $x$ has at least $3$ digits.

Let $A$ denote the set of integers with at most $2$ digits, so $A=\{1, ..., 99\}$. The previous paragraph shows that any orbit of $f$ passes infinitely often through $A$, therefore it must visit some element of $A$ twice, and thus it will be eventually periodic. To understand orbits of $f$, we therefore only need to understand the orbits of elements of $A$, which can be calculated on a computer. We find that $f$ has two fixed points, $1$ and $9$, and one cycle, $\{13, 16\}$.

Since $\delta(n)\equiv n\mod 9$, we have $f(n)\equiv n^2\mod 9$. By looking at what happens modulo $9$ under repeated squaring, we obtain, for *any* $n$, not just $n\in A$:

> 1. If $n\equiv 0, 3, 6\mod 9$, then the orbit of $n$ eventually hits the fixed point $9$.
> 2. If $n\equiv 1, 8\mod 9$, then the orbit of $n$ eventually hits the fixed point $1$.
> 3. If $n\equiv 2, 4, 7\mod 9$, then the orbit of $n$ eventually enters the cycle $\{13, 16\}$.

I imagine a similar approach would solve the case $f(x)=\delta(x^{2i})$ as well.

Comment: We got lucky that $1,9$ ${13,16}$ are in distinct orbits of $f(n)\equiv n^2\mod 9$ so similar approach will not really work in general. However I imagine is the best you can do without actually computing for a specific $g$ and $i$.

Comment: So instead of writing so many restrictions on $g$, all we can do is let $g \equiv 2, 4, 7, \mod 9$

Answer (score 1):

$$\LARGE \text{The $13$ Conjecture}$$

---

*For every natural number $g > 1$, if you square it, then take the sum of its digits, square the result, take the sum of digits of that, and so on, you will ultimately reach $13$*.

Since the digit sum of $g$ is divisible by $3$ if and only if $3$ divides $g$, my conjecture will thus lead to a different kind of loop, never reaching $13$ since $13 \neq 3h$ for all positive $h$.

Thus $3$ cannot divide $g$.

Since $1^2 = 1$, my conjecture will thus lead to *another* different loop if the digit sum of $g$ is equal to $1$. We established that $g > 1$, but $g \neq 10, 100, 1000, \ldots$

Thus $g \neq 10^n$, and in fact for some positive $i$, $g \neq (3h)^i \pm 1$. Of course if $h = 1$ and $i = 1$ then this is unsuitable, so $h, i > 1$. But $g \neq 3$ so we have no restrictions on $h$ apart from the fact that it is positive (with other added restrictions on $g$).

---

We can now re-write the conjecture by adding the necessary restrictions on $g$.

*For all natural numbers $h, n$ and all $g, i > 1$*:

$$
g \neq
\begin{cases}
 10^n, &\ 6(2n + 1) \pm 1 &\text{ for $n$}\\
 3h, &\ (3h)^i \pm 1&\text{ for $h$}
\end{cases}
$$

*Allowing these restrictions on $g$, square it, then take the sum of its digits, then square the result, take the sum of digits of that, and so on. Ultimately, you will reach $13$*.

---

**SECOND EDIT**

Comment: You wrote $g\not=10^n$, but for the conjecture you rewrote, $f_1(100)\to 1$ is still a counterexample.

Comment: Yes it is. That's why $g \neq 10^n$. Otherwise $f_1(10^n) \to 1$ which is a different loop, hence a counter-example.

Comment: @user477343: You don't write $g\not=10^n$ **in the conjecture**.

Comment: Because $10^n$ is of the form $(3h)^m + 1$. Let $m = 1$, and let $h = 3, 33, 333, \ldots$

Comment: $100$ is not of the form $(3h)^m+1$ where $m\gt 1$.

Comment: $100 = 99 + 1 = (3\times 33)^1 + 1$. Yes the "$m > 1$" part was a mistake

Comment: In the conjecture, you wrote $i\gt 1$.

Comment: Wait... what?? Hold up

Comment: Hah nice pickup!! :)

Comment: Why only $g\not=10$? Don't you mean $g\not=10^n$ where $n$ is a positive integer?

Comment: Now because for $n > 1$, it is of the form $(3h)^m + 1$ for $m > 1$....OH WAIT YOU KNOW WHAT? I NEED A BREAK. Thanks though mathlove :)

Comment: Now, $f_1(17)\to 1$ is a conterexample.

Comment: Because $17 = 18 - 1$.....

Comment: @user477343: Are you saying that $(3h)^i-1=17$ holds? For what $(h,i)$?

Comment: I edited it....again....

Comment: @user477343: Now, $f_1(19)\to 1$ is a counterexample. (in your initial conjecture, you wrote $g\not=18h\pm 1$, which looks good to me, but you deleted it in the conjecture you rewrote. And, excluding $3h-1$ is too much, I think. (you lost a lot of possible numbers.) Anyway, it's your decision:)

Comment: @mathlove I now write *for all $6(2n - 1) \pm 1* instead. Problem solved :)

Comment: $f_1(71)\to 1$ is a counterexample.